# WebStorm projects do not work outside of WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I am creating a project in WebStorm for a class that I am in. It seems that when I view the project and test it in WebStorm it uses localhost in the URL.

When I go to the files in the root folder the files don't seem to work. Is there something I have to do to export my project so it works when not specifying a port number?

Here is the link to the project if you care to look

https://github.com/joeythomaschaske/WoTCompanion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have a web server set up! WebStorm comes with a built in web server that makes debugging and quickly running apps/websites much smoother, but if you want to be able to view the site outside of WebStorm you're going to have to set up your own webserver.

A common open-source one is [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/), but there are many others you can use to get your desired results. There are many guides on how to set up your own web server, and many questions on Stack Overflow that deal with it too. Just search around and I'm sure you'll find something.

Comment: This was the issue. I just threw it in an App Engine project and sent it up into the cloud! Thanks